Map() data is getting lost
The stored data in export let connectedDevices = new Map(); in a renderer.js is lost after few activities in the app. we are basically storing HID devices in this Map and using it further, after a point we have a button in UI on click of it we need this connectedDevices which were seeing empty.
-------code piece where we set----------
const newDevice = new HID.HID(path);
connectedDevices.set(path, {
device: newDevice,
metadata: { model: null, serialNumber: null, firmwareVersion: null },
path,
receiveDataArray: [],
receiveDataRemaining: 0,
sendPacketsArray: [],
noOfPacketsSent: 0
});
Place where we fetch and see that as empty, both are in same file but different methods
tried global variables and IPC calls but no luck. Node-Hid objects are non-serialisable it seems.
